Unable to download tensorflow-macos 2.10 on VScode conda
As the title says, I am unable to download tensorflow-macos 2.10 on my vscode virtual environment. (Python 3.10.14) My laptop has an apple m1 chip, Big Sur(ver 11.7.6). From what I've searched this should meet the necessary requirements to download 2.10.
But when trying to download, the following error keeps happening.
> python3 -m pip install tensorflow-macos==2.10.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-macos==2.10.0 (from versions: 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-macos==2.10.0

I can download version 2.9 without any problem, but my code specifically needs tensorflow of version 2.10 or higher.
I've read people saying tensorflow-deps and numpy versions might be the problem, but I was perfectly able to download tensorflow-deps 2.10, and my numpy version is 1.23.2 as well. Aside from that I've been trying countless solutions from the internet as well but nothing explained why I am unable to download version 2.10.0 specifically. If I am missing something here, please tell me.

you may have to download source code and compile it for your system but it may takes even ~8 hours. You can also ask on yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels - maybe someone already compiled version for your system

Visited the site you linked but it doesnt seem to have any version I need. So I believe this is a problem with my computer system, not that I'm forgetting to download a specific thing... Oh well, guess I'll have to rebuild my code.
